# Killing a process does not work properly

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kill, raspbian

I am attempting to kill a process (see the code below) but I have no success.
This process running does not let me make new videos with the Raspberry Pi Camera and not even restart the Raspbian (which fixes the problem):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps -ef | grep raspi
pi       24267 22227  0 17:21 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto raspi
root     30071     1  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 [raspivid]
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo kill -9 30071
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ps -ef | grep raspi
pi       24420 22227  0 17:22 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto raspi
root     30071     1  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 [raspivid]
```

How can I kill this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the process a zombie or something unusual that's not kill-able? Check with

```
ps aux | grep raspi
```

looking at the STAT column (pipeing to `less` may help, then search within it for "raspi"). (See `man ps` for the different "PROCESS STATE CODES")